# Using a different result for each instance of insertion in gsub

Tags: ruby

Say my program such was thus:

```
my_string = "I think we should implement <random_plan> instead of <random_plan>"


 def generate_random_plan

   #Some code that returns a string that is not the same every time the method is called, involving randomness.

 end

puts my_string.gsub("<random_plan>", generate_random_plan)
```

So as I have written it, it would print something like "I think we should implement plan H instead of plan H". When what I really want is for `gsub` to call the method each time it performs a substitution, so I can end up with "I think we should implement plan D instead of plan Q". I have a sneaking suspicious the `gsub` method just isn't built for that and it can't be done, so could you suggest the easiest way to make this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One basic principle in Ruby is "when in doubt, try a code block." In fact, `gsub()` accepts a code block in place of a string for its second parameter.

Here's an example that is something like what you're looking for:

```
'axbxcxdxe'.gsub( 'x' ) { rand(9) }
```

Try that code in `irb` and you'll get random digits for the x's:

```
a0b6c0d3e
```

The replacement code block is a powerful feature, especially because it receives the original matched string as a parameter. As a contrived example, suppose you wanted to convert only the vowels in a string to uppercase:

```
def vowelup( s )
    s.gsub( /[aeiouy]/ ) { |c| c.upcase }
end

print vowelup( 'Stack Overflow' )
```

This prints:

```
StAck OvErflOw
```

JavaScript has essentially the same feature too:

```
function vowelup( s ) {
    return s.replace( /[aeiouy]/g, function( c ) {
        return c.toUpperCase();
    });
}

console.log( vowelup('Stack Overflow') );
```

Comment: why `rand(9)`? not 2,3 etc.

Comment: It's just an example showing how `gsub` calls a block and you can call a function such as `rand()` in that block. The actual numbers aren't significant. Of course the actual code would have something to do with the random responses the OP wants.

Comment: what's the diff between `'axbxcxdxe'.gsub( 'x' )` and `'axbxcxdxe'.gsub( 'x' ) { rand(9) }` ?

Comment: Try those both in `irb` and see what it says. The first one just returns an `Enumerator`.

Comment: Excellent, I am new to Ruby, so a code block wasn't even on my radar, but that is perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`gsub` accepts a block and, if given, calls it on each match. Return your random value from it.

```
my_string = "I think we should implement <random_plan> instead of <random_plan>"

def generate_random_plan s
  plans = ('A'..'Z').to_a
  s.gsub('<random_plan>') do
    plans.sample # random plan
  end
end

generate_random_plan my_string # => "I think we should implement A instead of J"
generate_random_plan my_string # => "I think we should implement Q instead of A"
generate_random_plan my_string # => "I think we should implement Z instead of H"
```